# How to find Pure-FTPd version

Tags: 10.04, ftp, version, pure-ftpd, package-info

I have installed Pure-FTPd on my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS?

Which command will give the version of the server running?

Comment: Is it displayed when you connect to the ftp server that is running?

Comment: @pl1nk No version info on welcome message `220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your Terminal and type the following command

`apt-cache showpkg pure-ftpd`

Comment: @jasminesIs Is this command dispalys versions installed in the system or the versions available on the repository?

Comment: Installed one, as you asked.

Answer (score 3):

The following command gives you the installed version, if you installed the package via the ubuntu repository

```
apt-cache policy pure-ftpd
```

Comment: After a bit of research, this does seem to be the best way to see what version is installed. pure-ftpd doesn't have an easy way to get the version.